# Setting cookie whilst form information is processed

Tags: php, forms, cookies

I am trying to find out why my cookie is not being set. I am attempting to set it in the same file the form information is processed. Here is my setup:

1. Page contains form
2. When submitted, all information is sent to: **form action="../../_includes/achieve-more-form-handler.php"**
3. Inside this form-handler is the set cookie script
4. User is then submitted back to the same page (because, if cookie is set, the page will have changed.)

Now, the way I find that it's not set in particular is, the form should not appear on step 1 if you come back to it whilst you have the cookie stored. But simply, there is no cookie being stored.

I get an email each time the form is filled in and I have received the email every time I've tested it so far, so all information regarding the form info is being processed etc as it should.

USER PAGE

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['achieve-more-cookie'])) {
    include(DOCUMENT_ROOT.'_includes/collapse-content.php');
} else {  ?>

<div id="step1">

    <div id="step1-formcontainer" class="ppc-forms">

    <h3>Example Heading #1</h3>

    <form action="../../_includes/achieve-more-form-handler.php" method="POST">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"<?php echo(isset($name)?' value="'.$name.'"':''); ?> required /><br />
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"<?php echo(isset($email)?' value="'.$email.'"':''); ?> required /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    </div>

</div>

<?php } ?>
```

FORM-HANDLER

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)) {

//set cookie
    $time = time() + 60;
    setcookie('achieve-more-cookie',$time);
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['achieve-more-cookie'];

.... the rest of this page is simply the form fields being processed etc.
```

Comment: Maybe it is being set but the page is cached (especially if you're using IE). Try setting no-cache headers on the page.

Comment: What's your redirect look like? And are you using IIS to serve your PHP?

Comment: @PeteScott Just using: header('Location: http://...')

Comment: If you re-navigate to the form page (via browser address bar, not a redirect), does it detect the cookie then? Also, I'm not sure if you intended this or not: you are setting the $time variable as the value of the cookie, not its expiration.

Comment: Nope still does not detect a cookie. I removed the redirect and simply made it echo 'thanks'. Navigated back to the page via typing in the address and still the form appears meaning no cookie is set. 

Also I removed the $time variable entirely regarding the cookie time/value for the moment.

Comment: http://dev.performancepartnership.com/Free-NLP-Resources/Achieve-More-In-30-Days/

Comment: Your cookie is being set. The page with the form is not detecting it, though. 
Name achieve-more-cookie
Value test
Host dev.performancepartnership.com
Path /_includes/
Expires Thu, 16 Oct 2014 01:38:29 GMT
Secure No
HttpOnly No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cookie is being set, but its path is set to the /_includes/ directory. That means that your form page doesn't have access to read the cookie.

```
Name    achieve-more-cookie
Value   test
Host    dev.performancepartnership.com
* Path  /_includes/
Expires Thu, 16 Oct 2014 01:38:29 GMT
Secure  No
HttpOnly    No
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path. A separate path can be configured using setcookie() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

```
setcookie('achieve-more-cookie','cookievalue',time()+60,'/');
```

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now, and yep worked the moment I updated to your suggested input, thank you!